# Is OWASP suitable for network security testing?

Tags: methodology, owasp, penetration-testing

I'm actually testing a mobile phone, from a security point of view.
I used the OSSTMM methodology, did the security tests, analysis, pen-test and so on.

I was wondering if there was a part of OWASP that could be used in this scope.
After doing a bit of research, it seems that it is really web-based content oriented. But as it is a huge methodology, I might have missed just what I was looking for.

So, is there something suitable from OWASP that could fit my scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no. In fact the W in OWASP stands for Web... that should have given me a clue...